# Right-hand Context Notation[DCG]

Tags: prolog, context-free-grammar, dcg, dcg-semicontext

in this [site](http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/dcg/), I found a part that explains how to build Right-hand Context Notation using DCG

```
A → ε | a A

Head, [T_1,...,T_n] --> Body.
```

someone help me figure out this method by example and illustrate its benefits to parse context-free grammar

Comment: That's outdated terminology. Please use a DCG text that is better maintained.

Comment: @mat That's outdated terminology! can you explain more

Answer (score 3):

This notation is called a **semicontext**. See, e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24184001/772868). With it you have strictly more power than context-free grammars. In fact, it is already type 0.

Comment: thnks,I found an interesting article [-ISO/IEC DTR 13211–3:2006](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dcgs/dcgsdraft-2015-11-10.pdf),  and I found the definition of semicontext in chap7.13.3.

Comment: @AnsPiter: Right, that's the most recent version.

Answer (score 2):

Look for Semicontext notation at [DCG Primer](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg.html): it's well explained, with examples

Comment: thnks, about yr link, `phrase_from_file//` it's not available in sicstus ,is there a (easy) solution ?

Comment: In SWI-Prolog, I use [read_file_to_codes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_file_to_codes/3), sometime also because phrase_from_file can be difficult to debug... Of course, file should be not huge.

Comment: Seems it's not available in SICSTUS... but should be easy to implement with read_line (to codes)

Comment: @CapelliC: Can you give an example where debugging without `phrase_from_file` is less difficult?

Comment: @false: when backtracking, it was almost impossible to me to understand the context. I had string//1 (from library(dcg/basics)) wrongly joined by empty productions, while parsing SQL backups. That was many years ago, not sure if the debugger behaves better now...

Comment: @AnsPiter: Here is [`pio`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/pio.pl) for SICStus - preliminary version. Do use it with `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).`  This will help you a lot in debugging, unless you know ASCII codes by heart.

Comment: @false thnk you VM, ,now I copy libraray pio into prolog preference or what ?

Comment: @false thnks, and is it possible to add library ([dcg_basics](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/http/dcg_basics.pl)) in sicstus ?

Comment: @AnsPiter: That library contains many impure definitions based on `codes` instead of `chars`.  I'd rather go without it.

Comment: @false   where I find .sicstusrc  in spider-eclipse

Comment: @AnsPiter: You need [the manual](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.3.2/html/sicstus/too_002dsicstus.html). Not sure how this applies to spider.

Comment: @false sorry,where I find .sicstusrc  in sisctus, is it path or file or something else ? you can illustrate the steps because I could not succeed to add 'phrase_from_file'

Comment: @AnsPiter: I put `.sicstusrc` in my home directory under Linux.

Comment: @AnsPiter: If you believe that the SPIDER doc is not good enough you can provide them [feedback on their pages](https://sicstus.sics.se/spider/)!

Comment: @false: Many thanks for providing the SICStus variant of this library! Could you please clarify the license conditions? Please be so generous as to put this library into the public domain, so that other systems can also freely use this important component.

Comment: I see. Thank you in any case for providing this.

Comment: @AnsPiter: Did you succeed in using `pio`?

Comment: @false I could not add this library :(

Comment: Simply add it as a normal file. And say `:- use_module(pio).` instead.